# filter and update field in object inside array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to add some id's to documents stored in a array and I'm struggling with figuring out how to do it.

The relevant models look like this:

```
Provider: 
{
 ObjectId Id { get; set; }
 List<Company> companies { get; set; }
}
Company:
{
ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently doing this to filter them out, but i don't know how to update them after filtering them out.

```
var CompanyIdIsNullFilter = Builders<Provider>.Filter.ElemMatch(p=>p.Companies,c => c.Id == null);
```

If I were to update providers without Ids I could do it simply like this in C#:

```
var ProviderIdIsNullFilter = Builders<Provider>.Filter.Eq(p=>p.Id,null);
var ProviderUpdate = Builders<Provider>.Update.Set(p => p.Id, ObjectId.GenerateNewId());
var result = await database.Providers.Provider.UpdateManyAsync(ProviderIdIsNullFilter , ProviderUpdate);
```

But I have no idea about how to do the set part when the relevant fields I want to update are inside the objects in a list

Comment: First you need to figure it out what is ObjectId in MongoDB. When you want to insert some record into MongoDB, you dont need to give him objectId, they will generate himself, so after that for every record you have objectId(hexadecimal). So, if you need some ID for Company or anything just declare them something unique, because you will always have objectId when you insert something.

Comment: This is for an existing collection, companies are only exist as a field in the array and don't have their own document in the db and there are currently many records where the value on Id is null so I know it's possible. New records are created like we want them on insertion, but what I'm trying to do is to go over the old ones missing Id and create one.